# Undefined Index error whenI run SYBUNT report

Tags: drupal, pantheon

I am getting the following error when I try to run the SYBUNT report:

> Notice: Undefined index: yid_value in
>   CRM_Report_Form_Contribute_Sybunt->where() (line 286 of
>   /srv/bindings/23131a86a5da4d9d91a43fa1623b947f/code/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form/Contribute/Sybunt.php).

Comment: What do you get when you try same on one of the CiviCRM Demo sites?

Comment: Thanks for your post. Could you provide more details about your environment? E.g. versions of CiviCRM, Drupal, PHP etc.

Answer (score 1):

that's just a notice - it's annoying - but may not be critical. You can check civicrm JIRA https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/projects/CRM/issues to see if there is an issue for it/report it (if not already).

If this is a live site then it's recommended not to display any errors. On Drupal go here:

```
admin/config/development/logging
```

and set to None.

Comment: It was causing a database error that was causing the SYBUNT and LYBUNT reports to not show.  I fixed it by reading the year a different way...which I suppose is a fine solution.